# How to build date histogram query which counts "new" properties

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, rollup, nosql

I am collecting data from devices and I want to build an understanding of when new devices come online. The documents are of the form:

```
{
  "device_id": "ue-0000"
}
```

I can query to see active devices over time buckets by doing a date histogram aggregation with nested term aggregations but I do not know how to express the logic of "filter out matches from bucket where `device_id` is present earlier in index".

Here's my current query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "2015/12/08",
            "lte": "2016/01/08"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "over_time": {
      "aggregations": {
        "app_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "app"
          }
        }
      },
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "day",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "2015/12/08",
          "max": "2016/01/08"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have docs like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2015/12/15",
    "device_id": "1"
}
{
    "timestamp": "2015/12/16",
    "device_id": "2"
}
{
    "timestamp": "2015/12/20",
    "device_id": "1"
}
```

Which I wan to return something like:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "over_time": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string":"2015/12/15 00:00:00",
          "key":1449532800000,
          "doc_count":1,
          "new_devices":{
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
            "sum_other_doc_count":0,
            "buckets":[{"device_id": "1"}]}
        },
        {
          "key_as_string":"2015/12/16 00:00:00",
          "key":1449532800000,
          "doc_count":1,
          "new_devices":{
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
            "sum_other_doc_count":0,
            "buckets":[{"device_id": "2"}]}
        },
        // [[ SNIP ]]
        {
          "key_as_string":"2015/12/20 00:00:00",
          "key":1449532800000,
          "doc_count":0, // there are no new device_ids on this date
          "new_devices":{
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
            "sum_other_doc_count":0,
            "buckets":[]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *device_id is present earlier in index*? could you give an example like sample doc and what kind of output you expect?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 good idea, I have added samples index docs and the kind of output desired.

Comment: did the solution help in solving the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add one more `terms aggregation` on `timestamp` which would give you only the **latest** unique device. Try something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "2015/12/08",
            "lte": "2016/01/08"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_device": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "device_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_date": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "size": 1,                   
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_device": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "interval": "day",
                "min_doc_count": 0,
                "extended_bounds": {
                  "min": "2015/12/08",
                  "max": "2016/01/08"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here `size` and `order` in `timestamp aggregation` will only give you new devices for `date histogram`.

Does this help?

Comment: This gave me the very useful `order._term` property of the terms aggregation but it wasn't enough to make this a one-stop shop. First problem: the query is slow on my dataset, taking 2s even with multiple calls (so it's not using the cache?). It is also not compatible with bucketing, it returns the oldest timestamp inside the bucket. I have used the query to make a postprocessing step and create a new index storing first-seen values.